# Try to use Google Translate API but get an error DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties

Tags: java, android, api, google-api, google-translate

I have already tried to add this code to gradle file

```
compile ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:0.5.0') {
exclude group: 'io.grpc', module: 'grpc-all'
exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
exclude group: 'com.google.api-client', module: 'google-api-client-
appengine'
```

}

But it gives me more errors.

So the main error after compilation is like
[image]

Is it a problem in gradle/dependecies OR it is a problem in authentication process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is add in gradle

```
     packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'project.properties' <------------------------here
    }
```